# Attaching a source dependency to a dependency with classifiers

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

I have this dependency:

```
testCompile group:"org.apache.mrunit", name:"mrunit", version:"1.+", classifier:'hadoop2'
```

I'm also using the `eclipse` plugin, but that dependency isn't getting its sources attached. The sources *are* there in Maven Central, hiding under the "sources" classifier, so I tried adding this:

```
testCompile group:"org.apache.mrunit", name:"mrunit", version:"1.+", classifier:'sources'
```

But that didn't solve my problem.

Any suggestion on how to attach the sources to a dependency? And should I file this as a bug under the Eclipse plugin or dependency resolution?

Comment: I don't think this case has been implemented. You might want to raise an issue at http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Done: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/attaching_source_information_to_dependencies_eg_for_use_in_the_eclipse_plugin

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Please @RobertFischer did you find a  solution??